# Having trouble binding data from C# to WPF to draw a line graph

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, data-binding, data-visualization

**Code Behind** - I have an Observable Collection of Points which holds data to plot to the graph. This data is read from an external source and will have anything from 20k-80k thousands values in each of these lists.

```
ObservableCollection<System.Windows.Point> listChannelData =new ObservableCollection <System.Windows.Point>();
ObservableCollection<System.Windows.Point> listActiveBaseline =new ObservableCollection <System.Windows.Point>();
```

Once these lists are populated, I then set the series ItemSource to these lists like so:

```
seriesChannelData.ItemsSource = listChannelData;
seriesActiveBaseline.ItemsSource = listActiveBaseline;
```

**XAML** - Not sure if the XAML is correct as just started learning, I also don't know if it's better to bind to the Observable Collection in the code or in the XAML.

```
<DVC:LineSeries Name="seriesChannelData" DependentValuePath="Y" IndependentValuePath="X" ItemsSource="{Binding seriesChannelData}" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
<DVC:LineSeries Name="seriesActiveBaseline" DependentValuePath="Y" IndependentValuePath="X" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
```

When I try to run this program it seems to take a long time to populate the lists and nothing charts, so it seems my data binding is wrong. Another thing I would like to find out is if I am wrong in setting the series item source to the lists after they have been populated.

Comment: I was researched about it many times but always the code was the best solution. It is really painful though.

Comment: Not sure what your exact question is, but binding to fields won't work. They need to be properties.

Comment: @Clemens Hi Clemens, I have updated the question to give more details, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```xml
<DVC:Chart Name="seriesChannelData" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="200"
DataContext="{Binding seriesChannelData}" IsTabStop="True" Background="White">
    <DVC:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Y" IndependentValuePath="X"
ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    </DVC:LineSeries>
</DVC:Chart>
```

In the `DataContext`, you will bind the observable collection Name and, in the `DependentValuePath` and `IndependentValuePath`, you bind the members of the observable collection.